Отложенная одноразовая отправка сообщений через телеграм бота aiogram 3.10.0
Здравия желаю, товарищи.
Пишу себе небольшой телеграм бот, используя aiogram 3.10.0. Логика данного бота заключается в следующем: получать текст и фотографию от пользователя, после запрашивать дату и время публикации и в нужный момент совершать публикацию с данным текстом и фото в определённый телеграм канал.
Если вкратце: бот должен совершать отложенную отправку сообщений.
И вот возник вопрос: какая библиотека позволила бы мне совершить задуманное? Пока что ничего нужного найти, к сожалению, не смог, поэтому рассчитываю на помощь более опытных товарищей.
Заранее премного благодарен!

На сколько далеко может быть отложена отправка? Это сутки, недели, месяцы, годы?

Недавно похожее обсуждение было здесь - с помощью celery cron. Если правильно понял, то идея записывать в БД заказы на публикации, и регулярно с помощью celery проверять её на наличие приближающихся по времени записей. Если такие есть - они отдаются приложению бота на выполнение.

AnnaBazueva - SPAM отправка в моём случае может быть отложена от 1 до 7 дней, не более

mrgervant премного благодарен, щас более детально ознакомлюсь с предоставленными материалами

Вышло решить данную задачу благодаря библиотеке AsyncIOScheduler.
Решение и способ применения смог найти в данной статье.

Надеюсь, мой вопрос и ответ на него в будущем кому-то смогут помочь.
